# Is it possible to render multiple plots within a single node in Code Workbooks?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-workbooks

In each node, I had had multiple visualizations for that model. Currently only that last one is shown. Is it possible to display the multiple plots for a node?

Answer (score 0):

Code Workbook will only display the last plot produced. In order to display multiple plots as an output, you need to combine them into a single plot by using  [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html).